# Passar dados de Javascript para método C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Preciso pegar a localização de um usuário, passar pro C#, pegar os dados da rua dele e mostrar numa label.

Tenho o seguinte código:

**Labels**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblLatitude" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblLongitude" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
```

**Javascript para pegar latitude e longitude**

```
<script>
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
}
else { alert("O seu navegador não suporta Geolocalização."); }
function showPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById('lblLatitude').textContent = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById('lblLongitude').textContent = position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

**Código do botão**

```
protected void btnLocalizei_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String latitude = lblLatitude.Text;
        String longitude = lblLongitude.Text;

        string url = string.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng={0},{1}&sensor=false", latitude, longitude);

        XElement xml = XElement.Load(url);

        if (xml.Element("status").Value == "OK")
        {
            lblMsg.Text = string.Format("<strong>Origem</strong>: {0}",
                xml.Element("result").Element("formatted_address").Value);
        }
        else
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "Ocorreu um erro";
        }
    }
```

Infelizmente não está passando os dados do javascript pro C# e não consigo ver erro no código :/

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: O ID do controle do lado do servidor não é necessariamente o mesmo no lado cliente. Veja se não é necessário setar manualmente a propriedade `ClientID` de cada um para ter o mesmo valor que a propriedade `ID`.

Comment: vale lembrar que para usar o mesmo id definido na sua pagina web, basta colocar o a Propriedade ClientIdMode="true" no seu controle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso sem precisar de chamar nenhum método em C#.

Um exemplo:

http://jsfiddle.net/moykn/N6x3q/

Como dito anteriormente o id do elemento no lado do geralmente não é o mesmo do lado do cliente, muitas vezes sendo formado pela concatenação dos ids dos parentes.

Uma opção seria no lugar de usar o document.getElementById usar jquery ou o querySelector

```
document.querySelector("[id$=lblLatitude]");
```

ou com Jquery

```
$("[id$=lblLatitude]");
```

Answer (score 7):

O `ID` para elementos ASP.NET gerados no servidor (`runat=server`) é atualizado em tempo de execução.

Use `<%= lblLatitude.ClientID %>` para referenciar o `ID` correto:

```
var latitude = "<%= lblLatitude.ClientID %>";
document.getElementById(latitude)(...)
```

Comment: Exato. O ID é resultado da concatenação dos IDs dos NamingContainer's em que o controle está inserido.

Comment: Ou altere o `ClientID` para ter o mesmo valor que o próprio `ID` se quiser deixar o código mais curto ;) mas isso funciona, +1.