# Como validar o retorno de um value usando Jquery em um componente que não suporta ClientIDMode="Static" no Asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quando se utiliza ASPNet WebForm, o `ID` dos componentes são alterados dinamicamente,mais este componente não tem como usar o ClientIDMode="Static" para se manter o mesmo ID.

***exemplo***:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="MenuSelecionado" value="processo" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="AbaSelecionado" value="aba1"  />
```

Resultado na máquina local:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MenuSelecionado"
      id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MenuSelecionado" value="processo">

<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$AbaSelecionado"
      id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AbaSelecionado" value="aba1">
```

Resultado no servidor:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MenuSelecionado" 
      id="ContentPlaceHolder1_MenuSelecionado" value="processo">

<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$AbaSelecionado" 
      id="ContentPlaceHolder1_AbaSelecionado" value="aba1">
```

Para se manter o padrão eu teria que pegar o “***name***” no lugar do `ID` ou validar o `value` recebido e trocar entre máquina local e remoto, exemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      //recebe o id do content 
      var menuatual = document  
        .querySelector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MenuSelecionado').value;
      //recebe o id da aba 
      var abaatual  = document
        .querySelector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AbaSelecionado').value;

      if (menuatual == "") { 
           // alert("não foi enviado nenhum menu no input");
      } else {
           //  alert("O menu que veio selecionado foi :" + menuatual);
           // alert("A Aba Selecionada foi :" + abaatual);

            // REMOVE AS CLASS ACTIVES DO TITULO
        $('.tab-content').find('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');

             // REMOVE AS CLASS ACTIVES DO CONTENT
       $('.nav.nav-tabs').find('li').removeClass('active')

        // alert("Removeu todas as active titulo");
        // alert("Removeu todas as active do content");
        //adiciona o active que retornou
        $('#'+abaatual).addClass('active'); 
        $('#'+menuatual).addClass('active in');

       }      
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Passar dados de Javascript para método C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7486/passar-dados-de-javascript-para-m%c3%a9todo-c)

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais prática quando não tem como usar o ClientIDMode="Static" e pegar pelo nome.
ficaria assim:

```
var menuatual = document.querySelector('input[name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MenuSelecionado"]').value
var abaatual  = document.querySelector('input[name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$AbaSelecionado"]').value
```

Comment: Você continua fazendo errado, porque alterou o nome do componente vai ter que ficar alterando em todos os lugares ...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, o name não altera, ele sempre vai vim assim, na minha máquina e na homologação o name e sempre o mesmo, já o ID se altera.